# Laravel 4 : How to make a sub-query with Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I have two tables. There is a table **place** that contains data as shown below:

```
id   name 
-----------
1    A1     
2    A2     
3    A3      
4    B1
```

Other table **place_conditions** contains data as sown below:

```
id   placeID     desription
----------------------------
1    1           Windy     
2    1           Dry     
3    3           Wet      
4    3           Rainy
4    4           Dry
```

I like to made a query in laravel 4 that make result like this below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => A1
            [place_cond] => Array
                               (
                               [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                       [description] => Windy
                                    )
                               [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                       [description] => Dry
                                    )
                               )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => A2
            [place_cond] => Array
                               (

                               )
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => A3
            [place_cond] => Array
                               (
                               [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                       [description] => Wet
                                    )
                               [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                       [description] => Rainy
                                    )
                               )
        )
)
```

Here part of my query (it still error) :

```
    $query = DB::table('place');
    if(Input::has('search')){
       $query->where(function($a){
          $a->where('name','LIKE','%'.Input::get('search').'%');
       });
    }
   /* $query->select('place.*',DB::raw('SELECT Description as place_cond FROM place_conditions WHERE place_conditions.placeID = place.id')); // sub query . Arrggghhhhhh... whyyyy.. stillllll.. errorrrrrrr.. */
    $data = $query->get();
```

Is possible to produce results like the above in laravel 4? Can you help me? Thank you